# Django not picking up the functions

Tags: python-3.x, django

I have tried every thing from making new function and saving every file thrice but nothing seems to work. And its my first time using Django if any one find  anything please point it out...
Note: Django ver 3.1

Server Error:

```
    path('', views.home_view),
AttributeError: module 'pages.views' has no attribute 'home_view'
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'products', 'pages',
]
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
# Create your views here.


def home_view(*args, **kwargs):
    return HttpResponse("Hello world")
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from pages import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home_view),
]
```

Comment: In which file location the function `home_view(....)` is located?

Comment: It seems like everything is fine. Please make sure you've imported your `urlpatterns` perfectly.

Comment: i've double checked every thing

Answer (score 0):

in urls.py change "from pages import views" to "from . import views"